# ValueError: Invalid coordinate dimensionality

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, geopandas, shapely

I have looked for this error everywhere. Shapely did not provide anything about it.

What I am trying to do is convert multiple LineStrings into Multilinestring and convert it back to one LineString with ops.linemerge

```
list_lines = '''[ LINESTRING Z (106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513,
        106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879),
        LINESTRING Z (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501,
        106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539) ]'''

multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString(list_lines)

ValueError: Invalid coordinate dimensionality
```

Answer (score 0):

Really this is a combination of string tokenisation followed by conversion to a **list** of **shapely** line string objects.  Finally build a **MultiLineString** from **list** of line strings

Last step if you want a string is to **wkt** encode it.

```
import shapely.wkt, shapely.geometry
import re

list_lines = """[ LINESTRING Z (106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513,
        106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.08756605785879),
        LINESTRING Z (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.70117552089501,
        106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.32231714313539) ]"""

list_lines = list_lines.replace("\n", "")


shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(
    [
        shapely.wkt.loads("LINESTRING Z " + t.strip(" []"))
        for t in re.split("LINESTRING Z", list_lines)
        if len(t.strip(" []")) > 0
    ]
).wkt
```

#### output

```
'MULTILINESTRING Z ((106.859360409289 43.0466887338676 -90.3134785987513, 106.859493724627 43.0466608020767 -90.0875660578588), (106.860395798461 43.0474727994385 -90.701175520895, 106.860856566526 43.0479333434232 -92.3223171431354))'
```